# parallel time in Awake

Tags: awake

The protagonist of the series *Awake* (2012) lives in two worlds: one in which his wife died in a car crash, and one in which their son died instead. As we see it, he spends a day in Hannah’s timeline and then a day in Rex’s, alternating.

But (in the four episodes I’ve seen) no one ever asks him where he goes on the other days. On the other hand, if he lives each calendar day twice in sequence, he ought to be able to use knowledge of events unrelated to his family to win the occasional bet, and I haven’t seen him do that.

Perhaps his awareness forks each morning, and rejoins when he sleeps, so that he always has two yesterdays, neither preceding the other.

Did the show ever establish how Michael perceives sequence between the two timelines?

Comment: I'm amazed that there's no tag for “alternate timeline” or “multiverse” or “parallel worlds” …

Comment: Because those aren't *direct* topics of this site, only indrectly through discussing film plots involving these things.

Comment: Okay, maybe this belongs on scfi.se

Comment: I was only talking about your comment on the tags. I haven't assessed the question yet.

Answer (score 2):

> [Awake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awake_(TV_series)) garnered critical praise, particularly for Isaacs' performance.
>   However, its ratings were low, averaging 4.8 million viewers per
>   episode and sitting in 125th place in viewership for the 2011–12
>   season. **The series was canceled after one season.**

Unfortunately there is no way to tell *exactly* what was going on here, because the series was canceled after the first season, leaving its mythology mostly unexplained, as no one ardently comes to contest Micheal Britten's situation.

> **His therapists insist that he is imagining it all** to help cope with
>   the pain. However, when Michael later breaks into Ed's house Ed
>   admits that he and an accomplice were hiding heroin at the Westfield
>   Distribution Center; **"they decided he had to go", after Michael began
>   to uncover it.**

However, as the show moved towards it's season one finale, Micheal's therapist begins to believe him, as his information from the other reality becomes useful in unearthing the people behind the accident and because Michael begins to remember details from the accident. But that is as close as the show got into proving that he was somewhere else whenever he was sleeping.

---

One possible explanation they could have come up with was that the character's body might have physically remained in his universe and his consciousness just hijacked the body of his alternate. In science fiction terms this is known as "conscious time traveling" (e.g.: *LOST, Fringe*). However there is no proof which way anything was happening or how what was happening is possible.